# Setting a default value for radio button inside foreach loop- MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Every items have different radio button values. But it showing the last radio button checked for every record.

I have put "checked" and checked="checked" in input field but it showing me the only last radio button checked for each record

```
<div class="radio input-group col-lg-12">
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span> Select Tour Guide:</span>
 @foreach (var item in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TourGuides)
  {
     <label style="padding-right:50px"><input name="TourGuideId" type="radio" value="@item.Value" checked="checked" /> @item.Text </label>
   }
</div>
```

I want to get different radio button checked for different records which I have define in database

Comment: radiobuttons are mutually exclusive.  you can't have multiple radiobuttons with the same name and have them all checked.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="radio input-group col-lg-12">
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span> Select Tour Guide:</span>
 @foreach (var item in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TourGuides)
  {
     <label style="padding-right:50px" for="@item.Value"><input name="TourGuideId" id="@item.Value" type="radio" value="@item.Value" checked="checked" /> @item.Text </label>
   }
</div>
```

Try this code in which add id in input field and add for in label.

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is a boolean, so you should just be able to pass `checked` as a prop when you want the radio button to be checked, or not include it at all when you don't.

```html
     <label style="padding-right:50px"><input name="TourGuideId" type="radio" value="@item.Value"  /> unchecked </label>
     <label style="padding-right:50px"><input name="TourGuideId" type="radio" value="@item.Value" checked /> checked </label>
```